# UK tourist visa is expiring, but I can't use it because of Covid-19

Tags: uk, covid-19, event-based-effects, nigerian-citizens, visa-expiration

I am from Nigeria. I got my UK tourist visa in February, but am unable to travel yet due to restrictions from Nigeria to UK. My visa will expire in August.

What will happen if the restriction is still in place and my visa expires before I can use it?

Comment: Your visa will expire and you’ll have to reapply if you want to travel to the UK

Comment: @Traveller that's an answer